# Video.js - loadeddata event never fires

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I am integrating Video.js into a project and having a few issues.

I have it in my HTML as:

```
<video id="vidView" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320" height="320" 
   poster="/siteImages/Dummy.png" preload="auto">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="" \>
</video>
```

And in my javascript I load a source and manage to play it.

```
var vidPlayer = _V_("vidView");
vidPlayer.src({ type: "video/mp4", src: vidlink });

vidPlayer.play();
```

Only doing this programmatically was having issues - every second load of a source and play would work.  I imagined I was trying to play before video.js was ready, so sought to use listeners to launch play at the proper time.

I have found that certain events never fire at all.  I can't get anything from "loadedalldata" event or "loadeddata".   The "loadstart" event fires at least, so I put my .play() command in there.

```
vidPlayer.addEvent("loadstart", function(){ console.log("LOAD START Fired" );
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.play(); 
} );
```

But it's still not reliable.  I see messages on my console of "Trying to resume!" several times. It plays for a few videos, but gets bogged down sometimes.

Am I missing something in getting "loadeddata" event to happen?

Also, related Q - I notice that the docs say the syntax for removing an Event listener is:

myPlayer.removeEvent("eventName", myFunc);

Is that right?  It seems like the "myFunc" part is redundant, and I'm wondering if that is a copy/paste error in [the documentation](https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md)  or if that's correct syntax.

Thx in advance.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your `poster` URL (the `' %}` ), which may also be related.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you ran into the same issue I did. If your browser is using the HTML5 video (instead of Flash fallback) Some events, like `loadedmetadata` and `loadeddata`, may fire before Video.js binds the event listeners.

This is particularly true if you are doing some preloading, and there is a delay between when the video start to load and when you initialising Video.js. It also seems to occur when there is a cached copy, which is why it works on every second refresh (invalidating the cache).

The solution is to just throw your video initlisation stuff in the `<head>` instead of at the bottom of the document. If that is not ideal (which it wasn't for us), we added an event listener to the `<head>` and then checked for it after we initialised the player. For example

In `<head>`:

```
<script>
var loadedmetadata = false;
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(ev) {
            loadedmetadata = true;
    }, true);
}
</script>
```

And then later in your script:

```
if (loadedmetadata === true && videoPlayer.techName === 'html5') {
    // call the callback you would have attached to
    // the event listener.
} else {
    // add event listener here
]
```

`window.addEventListener` is not supported in IE7/8, but thats okay, because they don't support HTML5 video anyway, so it won't ever fire. IE9 supports `window.addEventListener` and HTML5 video, so it will work as expected.

We also check that the `techName` is `html5`, since the Flash player is created when we initialise the Video.js object, so the event shouldn't have fired previously.

Comment: Thx for the tips: Still feeling my way through that. Sounds like helpful tips.

Answer (score 1):

`loadeddata` won't necessarily fire before playback starts. In Flash it never does, with HTML5 the event is relayed from the video element so it depends on the browser behaviour.

`loadedalldata` is when the entire video is downloaded, so is unlikely to occur before playback starts.

You specify which function to remove from the event because you could have bound more than one function to the event, e.g.

```
vidPlayer.addEvent("play", onPlay1 );
vidPlayer.addEvent("play", onPlay2 );
vidPlayer.removeEvent("play", onPlay1 ); // onPlay2() would still be executed
```