# Video.js producing intermittent issues

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, video.js

Have a website that is producing intermittent errors. So far mostly in Chrome. Video loads the majority of the time, but I would say about 10-15% of the time, nothing loads and I get an error logged in the console. Refreshing the page after error usually resolves the issue.

Error:

```
["Video Error", Object]
0: "Video Error"
1: Object
    AT_TARGET: 2
    BLUR: 8192
    BUBBLING_PHASE: 3
    Bb: function c(){return f}
    CAPTURING_PHASE: 1
    CHANGE: 32768
    CLICK: 64
    DBLCLICK: 128
    DRAGDROP: 2048
    FOCUS: 4096
    KEYDOWN: 256
    KEYPRESS: 1024
    KEYUP: 512
    MOUSEDOWN: 1
    MOUSEDRAG: 32
    MOUSEMOVE: 16
    MOUSEOUT: 8
    MOUSEOVER: 4
    MOUSEUP: 2
    NONE: 0
    SELECT: 16384
    bubbles: false
    cancelBubble: true
    cancelable: true
    clipboardData: undefined
    currentTarget: video#my_video_1_html5_api.vjs-tech
    defaultPrevented: false
    eventPhase: 2
    initEvent: function initEvent() { [native code] }
    mc: function d(){return l}
    preventDefault: function (){e.preventDefault&&e.preventDefault();a.returnValue=l;a.zb=c}
    relatedTarget: undefined
    returnValue: true
    srcElement: video#my_video_1_html5_api.vjs-tech
    stopImmediatePropagation: function (){e.stopImmediatePropagation&&e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    stopPropagation: function (){e.stopPropagation&&e.stopPropagation();a.cancelBubble=f;a.Bb=c}
    target: video#my_video_1_html5_api.vjs-tech
    timeStamp: 1375812343815
    type: "error"
    which: undefined
    zb: function d(){return l}
    __proto__: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

Not much I can get from that.

I ran into this thread, but the main fix seems to involve moving code the , which I did with no change in behaviour. [Video.js - loadeddata event never fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195331/video-js-loadeddata-event-never-fires)

Javascript:

```
 _V_("my_video_1").ready(function(){

    var myPlayer = this;

                    sizeVideo(); //used to adjust my canvas so it fits in design based of screen width

        myPlayer.play();

    });


    function sizeVideo(){
      var viewSizeWidth=$('.video_wrapper').width();
      var viewSizeHeight=parseInt(viewSizeWidth/1.7791);
      var videoWrapperHeight=parseInt($('.video_wrapper').height());
      $('#my_video_1 ').width(viewSizeWidth);
      $('#my_video_1 ').height(viewSizeHeight);
      $('#my_video_1 video').width(viewSizeWidth);
      $('#my_video_1 video').height(viewSizeHeight);

        if(viewSizeHeight> videoWrapperHeight ){
          var heightOffset=(viewSizeHeight-videoWrapperHeight)/2;
          $('#my_video_1 video').css('top','-' + heightOffset + 'px');
          $('.video_wrapper').height(700);

        }else{
          $('#my_video_1 video').css('top','0px');
          $('.video_wrapper').height(viewSizeHeight);
                      }


    }
```

html

```
     <video id="my_video_1"  class='video-js vjs-default-skin'   preload="auto" data-setup='{"controls": false,"loop":"true"}'  autoplay poster='/img/video-placeholder.jpg'>
           <source src="/vid/corp.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            <source src="/vid/corp.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
           <source src="/vid/corp.webm" type='video/webm'>


       </video>
```

I'm a bit stumped, and I'm not too comfortable with it working "most of the time".

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be dealing with a very dated version of videojs. I've been working with one of the most recent versions of it and have amended a few things. My edits allow you to click anywhere on the thumbnail of the video of a mobile instead of exactly in the center. It also allows responsive videos = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html